# How do you prevent Ant from display [java] in the command window?

Tags: java, ant

When you run a Java file through Ant, all of the output has the `[java]`-tag in front of it.

How do you remove this?

**Example:**

```
 [java]            |            *
 [java]            | :irc.cs472.cs.drexel.edu
 [java]            | 372 test :- *    Welcome
 [java]            | on our new IRC server, ru
 [java]            | nning on:  *
 [java]            | :irc.cs472.cs.drexel.edu
 [java]            | 372 test :- *    Debian G
 [java]            | NU/Linux (www.debian.org)
 [java]            |            *
 [java]            | :irc.cs472.cs.drexel.edu
 [java]            | 372 test :- *************
 [java]            | *************************
 [java]            | ************
 [java]            | QUIT
 [java] Type \m to | :irc.cs472.cs.drexel.edu
 [java]  bring up  | NOTICE test :Connection s
 [java] the menu a | tatistics: client 0.1 kb,
 [java] t any time |  server 1.6 kb.
 [java] ___________________________________
 [java] Please enter your choice :

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 minute 39 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Just run ant with emacs parameter to get rid of the adornments, f.e. :

```
ant -emacs -f build.xml
```

see [ant manual command line options](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#options)

Answer (score 0):

You could used `sed`. Pipe the `ant` output into...

```
sed " s/^\[JAVA\] //"
```

Comment: I was wondering if there was an option in ant. Without having to pipe the output.

Comment: I have tried this solution and it does not change the output at all I typed
ant IRCClient | sed " s/^\[JAVA\] //"

Comment: @Angel You're not escaping the brackets. You need to, otherwise `sed` will treat them as a character class.